# How to remove the queue working of settimeOut?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After `clearTimeout(tt);`, `tt = setTimeout(function () {` is stopped to work. Why? I have the Recursion and when i execute getByClients in manually i need to remove current queue of setTimeout(if exists) and execute new setTimeout, instead after `clearTimeout(tt);` i am getting nothing.

```
var tt = undefined;
// in default select = null, only by btn click='getByClients(1)'
function getByClients(select) {

  if (select == 1 || select == 2) {
    clearTimeout(tt); // after, setTimeout is not executed 
  }

    dashboardService.getByClients($scope.clientsMode).then(function(response) {
        tt = setTimeout(function() {
          getByClients(null);
        }, refreshTime);

  });
};
```

HELP, someone, please (

Comment: Recursion is generally not a good idea in JavaScript that's why they created set timeout and for loops. Also you never call the initial getByClients so it never runs to begin with and in the second instance and you pass it two parameters when it only has 1 . Also your if statement is not an if else stamens meaning for all the code you've given it's entirely possible to have the setTimeout reset after it's been cleared

Comment: @Binvention,  missed removing params of functions, for showing of example

Comment: @Binvention "Recursion is generally not a good idea in JavaScript that's why they created set timeout and for loops." That's not true at all. It's just that you have to be careful when writing recursive code.

Comment: Well technically when looked at closely this isn't recursion at all. Because the then function implies a callback it means it's not running synchronously. So getByClients is not defined with itself but that callback function does include it. Recusing becomes dangerous when the function calls itself synchronously because then you have multiple instances of the same function running before the first can finish but that isn't the case here the first function can finish without being dependent on the second instance

Comment: @AxOn the other thing about your problem is it's not contained within this code. The code here could work given the right external circumstances although assuming you're dashboard service always resolves rather then rejects this will run continually on the interval of your refresh time because even if the timeout is cleared the dashboard service again initializes it so it's just a longer delay than normal

Comment: @Binvention, so, maybe you have some advice or example(better), how should to make it better? i dunno (

Comment: First of all what starts the first instance of the getByClients and does the dashboard service ever reject. Does the dashboard service resolve quickly or does it take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Is getByClients run multiple times before the interval is stopped. (Because if so that means you could have multiple timeouts running but only one named one. So you stop the named one but the others keep running)

Comment: @Binvention,  $timeout.cancel(p); behave self like clearTimeout ((

Comment: Yes it should behave the same

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need of recursive code. Perhaps your sample is too simplified ?
If I understand correctly, you need to automatically call a service every X seconds, but you want to be able to force immediate call.
In this case here is how I would do that :

```
var tt = null;


// - Stop current timer (is started)
function stopTimeout()
{
    if(tt)
  {
        clearTimeout(tt); 
    tt = null;
  }
}


// - Start a new Timer (and stops the previous one if any)
function startTimeout()
{
        stopTimeout(); // - to clean if already started (security)

    tt = setTimeout(function() {
          getByClients();
    }, refreshTime);
}


function getByClients()
{
    // - Stop automatic Timer
    stopTimeout();

  // - Executes Query
    dashboardService.getByClients($scope.clientsMode).then(function(response) {
        // - "Read response "

    // - Restart timer
    startTimeout();

        }
    );
}

// - Start automatic calls
getByClients();
```

There is no need in this case for a parameter : each call stops current timeOut.
I think a better way could be to use a setInterval, but I wanted to be near your original code.

My example code restarts automatic updates after a manual one. I don't know if this is your need ?

EDIT : I see you use AngularJS, perhaps $timeout would better suit your needs ?

Comment: He was wanting the interval to be stopped by a button click.